# Timestamp to datetime conversion results in 2082 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I have following timestamp generated by a c++ app for recording files: `

> 3557588270.0

I want to convert this timestamp in python, with

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(3557588270.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but the result is:

> 2082-09-25 18:57:50

and the result should be:

> 2019-12-06 09:19:..

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: I forgot one important fact: in the documentation of the recording application, the timestamp is given as: 
`Time stamp in UNITS (10000000 per second)` 
[The link to the documentation](http://documentation.evocortex.com/libirimager2/html/structevo_1_1IRFrameMetadata.html#a09a5186c9dd4639a361880b227e76f0f)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not on the conversion. The problem is that your input value (3557588270) does not lead to your expected datetime value, as you can see on [this site](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: I cannot change the input value, which comes from recording videos in binary format.

Comment: @AlexPab it seems that the error comes from there... Probably the recorder was set on the wrong datetime in such a way. For sure 3557588270.0 leads to 2082-09-25 18:57:50

Comment: @AlexPab do you know what's the meaning of timestampMedia? Can you retrieve its value?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot retrieve the timestampMedia data... I only have the timestamp value for every frame...